# How to handle test_specs that have common sources

Tags: cocoapods

Using cocoapods version 1.6.0.rc.1 and cocoapods-generate, I have two test_specs like below:

```
  s.test_spec 'UnitTests' do |test_spec|
    test_spec.requires_app_host = false
    test_spec.source_files = 'MyThing/Tests/Common/**/*.{h,m}'
    test_spec.source_files = 'MyThing/Tests/Unit/**/*.{h,m}'
  end

  s.test_spec 'EndToEndUnitTest' do |test_spec|
    test_spec.requires_app_host = true
    test_spec.source_files = 'MyThing/Tests/Common/**/*.{h,m}'
    test_spec.source_files = 'MyThing/Tests/EndToEnd/**/*.{h,m}'
  end
```

both test_specs have the line

```
    test_spec.source_files = 'MyThing/Tests/Common/**/*.{h,m}'
```

but cocoapods-generate can't figure out which target the common sources belong to, so they are omitted from the project.

**How can I define a set of sources that are common across test_specs?**

Answer (score 0):

The Podspec is Ruby, and I was overwriting the previous source_files variable value with the second line. I'm dumb.

https://github.com/square/cocoapods-generate/issues/14